# How to delete a folder with weird files inside?

Tags: windows, directory, delete

I was cleaning up some disk space on my windows pc when I noticed this old folder that I had from back when this PC also ran linux. I tried deleting the folder through windows but some of the files inside had a colon in the file name and that seemed to mess with windows. I tried deleting the files through the ubuntu sub system on windows but that didn't work either. Here is what I tried.

```
$ sudo ls
man3  <-- this is the dir to delete
```

```
$ rmdir man3
rmdir: failed to remove 'man3': Directory not empty
```

```
$ sudo rm -r man3
rm: cannot remove 'man3/Locale::gettext.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'man3/Text::CharWidth.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'man3/Text::Iconv.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'man3/Text::WrapI18N.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
```

this is where I don't really understand what is happening. Im using the recursive delete but its somehow detecting a file to delete, and then not finding it?

anyways I went into the dir and this is what I tried.

```
/man3$ ls -li
ls: cannot access 'Locale::gettext.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Text::CharWidth.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Text::Iconv.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Text::WrapI18N.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
total 0
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Locale::gettext.3pm.gz
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Text::CharWidth.3pm.gz
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Text::Iconv.3pm.gz
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Text::WrapI18N.3pm.gz
```

Anyone know how to deal with these files? Im guessing its some sort of corruption but I can't find a way to just get rid of them. I've also tried touch on some of the files this happens.

```
/man3$ touch Locale\:\:gettext.3pm.gz
/man3$ ls -li
ls: cannot access 'Text::CharWidth.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Text::Iconv.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Text::WrapI18N.3pm.gz': No such file or directory
total 0
28428972647776675 -rwxrwxrwx 1 serry serry 0 Apr 11 15:35 Locale::gettext.3pm.gz
28428972647776675 -rwxrwxrwx 1 serry serry 0 Apr 11 15:35 Locale::gettext.3pm.gz
                ? -????????? ? ?     ?     ?            ? Text::CharWidth.3pm.gz
                ? -????????? ? ?     ?     ?            ? Text::Iconv.3pm.gz
                ? -????????? ? ?     ?     ?            ? Text::WrapI18N.3pm.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot directly to Linux on a disc or memory card to remove the files.

Linux is able to use characters in filenames that Windows does not consider valid. WSL is unable to access the files because Windows is still being used to access the filesystem.